# Start and Stop Windows Service from my ASP.net MVC application

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, windows-services

I have a MVC application in asp.net MVC 3.0, i need to start and stop a service which is nothing but file processing service and made by us , i have added 2 button for toggle the service status , start and stop but getting exception , can not open my service ,

Any one has any idea how to handle this?
and also sample code are welcome , i have tried identity on web config along with my user id and password  but it's does not work for me :(,

Guys please help me..

Comment: What is the code you are using to control the service?

Comment: I bet on a permission issue. Is your asp.net process identity allowed to control services?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: What does "can not open my service" mean? What have you tried and what is the result?